# Chrome Extension - Changing User Agent - Permissions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm trying to change the user agent from the extension popup. As I searched the web, it seems possible with the webRequest API and webRequestBlocking (for Manifest V2) or declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess (I'm not sure about this one).

I already have the webRequest permission in my extension, but webRequestBlocking is not included and I don't want to add it because it will affect all users.

My question is: Is there a way to achieve this without requiring or adding webRequestBlocking or declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess to my permissions, even as optional permissions?

Comment: You can add webRequestBlocking 
 or declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess to permissions without problems because they don't have a warning so the extension won't be disabled on update.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm, thank you for your answer! I missed something though. I don't have the webRequest permission in my extension too :/ webRequest has "read browsing history" warning and other permissions in my extension has already requires this warning. So, If I add webRequest permission, will extension be disabled on current users?

Comment: The webRequest permission doesn't have any warnings on its own, at least in Chrome, so adding it won't disable the extension in Chrome.